# How to model negative zero-inflated continuous data?

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, glmm, zero-inflation, sentiment-analysis

I am currently trying to apply a model (family = gaussian) to an indicator of sentiment score, values range from -4 to +2, is zero-inflated and is continuous.

I want to look whether there is a relationship between the way a question is asked (positive, negative, neutral wording) and the sentiment of the response. I have 2638 people asked a question about symptoms. 1/3 of the people were asked it with a negative wording, 1/3 with a neutral one, 1/3 with a positive one. From this, I did sentiment analysis (using Trincker's package) to see whether their responses were more positive or negative, depending on the wording of the question.

Sentiment analysis breaks down responses into sentences, so I have 2638 people, but 7924 sentences, so I would assume to fit ID as a random effect?

The big question is: does the way the question is asked (primetype) affect the polarity of the response?
At first, I thought perhaps a glmm with gaussian family, but as my data is slightly negative skewed, with many 0s (more neutral answers) that didn't work. I have now made 3 more variables: 'neg counts' which scores 1 for each row that has the sentiment score below 0. Idem for neutral (sentiment=0) and positive (sentiment>0).

Then I run 3 independent glmm poisson, with the counts of how many sentences are the emotion in question.
Model 1: counts of how many sentences are positive
Model 2: counts of how many sentences are neutral
Model 3: counts of how many sentences are negative

Currently, my model is:

```
posmodel <- glmer(formula = poscount~primetype+ (1|id),data=allprimesent, family="poisson")
summary(posmodel)
```

and output:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum
  likelihood (Laplace Approximation) [glmerMod]
 Family: poisson  ( log )
Formula: poscount ~ primetype + (1 | id)
   Data: allprimesent

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  7413.1   7441.0  -3702.6   7405.1     7920 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.4696 -0.3941 -0.3941 -0.3839  2.2207 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id     (Intercept) 0        0       
Number of obs: 7924, groups:  id, 2638

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -1.51188    0.04692 -32.223  < 2e-16 ***
primetype2  -0.40273    0.06669  -6.038 1.56e-09 ***
primetype3  -0.35048    0.06680  -5.246 1.55e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
           (Intr) prmty2
primetype2 -0.703       
primetype3 -0.702  0.494
optimizer (Nelder_Mead) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

I would love to know if others think this is the right way to analyse this? And also whether my glmm looks right, as my random effects are coming out as 0! Sorry this is so long!!!

EDIT:
I've gone back to looking at a glmm, using the glmmTMB package. My data is negatively skewed, and has a lot of 0s (this is because some people felt 'neutral'  and so they scored '0'.

Model:

```
glmmTMB(sentiment ~ primetype + age + (1|id), data=DF)
```

Output:

```
Family: gaussian  ( identity )
Formula:          sentiment ~ primetype + age + (1 | id)
Data: sentancedf

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  7254.9   7296.5  -3621.4   7242.9     7556 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups   Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 id       (Intercept) 8.732e-11 9.344e-06
 Residual             1.526e-01 3.906e-01
Number of obs: 7562, groups:  id, 2520

Dispersion estimate for gaussian family (sigma^2): 0.153 

Conditional model:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -0.1655972  0.0204310  -8.105 5.27e-16 ***
primetype2   0.0907564  0.0114045   7.958 1.75e-15 ***
primetype3   0.0977533  0.0115802   8.441  < 2e-16 ***
age         -0.0020644  0.0006483  -3.184  0.00145 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
```

How can I interpret whether the model is a good one for my data? Should I use 0 inflated model? I can't use poisson or binonial...

Comment: The model has converged to a singular fit, so you defintiely have a problem there. Can you explain this: *as my data is slightly negative skewed, with many 0s (more neutral answers) that didn't work* ? In what sense did that model not work ? The distribution of the data is not relevant.

Comment: Hi @RobertLong ! I've now actually gone back to my original GLMM, please check my edited Q above :)